# Integration substitution $ \sqrt {x^2+a^2} $

Tags: integration

Hi I am learning calculus on my own and encountering a question about integration by substitution.
For example, we can use $16-x^2= t^2 $ to get $\mathrm dx$ (as the picture shows) and insert it back into the integrand.

> Using integration by substitution $t^2=16-x^2$ so that $-x\,\mathrm dx=t\,\mathrm dt$, then$$\begin{align*}\int\frac {x^3}{\sqrt{16-x^2}}\,\mathrm dx & =\int\frac {x^2\cdot x}{\sqrt{16-x^2}}\,\mathrm dx\\ & =\int\frac {t(t^2-16)}{t}\,\mathrm dt\\ & =\int t^2-16\,\mathrm dt\\ & =\frac 13t^3-16t+C\\ & =\frac 13(16-x^2)^{3/2}-16\sqrt{16-x^2}+C\end{align*}$$

However, if I try to use this technique to solve the question
$ \int \sqrt {x^2+a^2}dx $, the answer is totally different from using trigonometric substitution.

$ {x^2+a^2} = t^2 $ so $ 2x\,\mathrm dx= 2t\,\mathrm dt $.

Then,

$\int\sqrt{x^2+a^2}dx=\int tdt $. However, this will generate a different answer to the correct solution.

Am I missing some fundamental theorems here?

Comment: In the title, do you mean $\sqrt{x^2+a^2}$ ?

Comment: sorry, not familiar with Latex

Comment: Please clarify with a question edit which problem you're working on. For instance, are you asking about what happens if you substitute $t=\sqrt{x^2+a^2}$ to evaluate e.g. $\int\sqrt{x^2+a^2}\mathrm{d}x$?

Comment: Sorry for not expressing the question correctly. I have updated my question.

Comment: For your second integral, $$ \ dx \ = \ \frac{t}{x} \ dt \ = \ \frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2 - a^2} } \ dt \ \ . $$  So $$  \int \sqrt{x^2+a^2} \ dx \ \ = \ \ \int \frac{t^2}{\sqrt{t^2 - a^2}} \ dt  \ \ . $$  Your first integral could be done by $ "  u-$substitution", but you're out of luck on the second one...

Comment: Simply, you got $t\,dt = x\, dx$ and then proceeded as if you got $dt = dx$, which is not true since $t$ and $x$ are different.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I now see what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're facing is with the line

$$\int\sqrt{x^2+a^2}\,\mathrm dx\neq\int t\,\mathrm dt$$

The reason for that is because in performing the substitution $t^2=x^2+a^2$, you have that $x\,\mathrm dx=t\,\mathrm dt$. In the integral

$$\int\frac {x^2\cdot\color{blue}{x}}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}\,\mathrm dx$$

There is an additional $x$ term inside the integral highlighted in blue. That makes this substitution convenient because we can then replace the $x\,\mathrm dx$ with a $t\,\mathrm dt$.

However, in the $\sqrt{x^2+a^2}$ integral, the integrand only has the square root term (i.e., there is no trailing $x$ term inside the integral such that you can replace $x\,\mathrm dx$ with. Instead, we must have

$$\mathrm dx=\frac tx\,\mathrm dt=\frac {t}{\sqrt{t^2-a^2}}\,\mathrm dt$$

Which doesn't really help you solve the problem. If you want to avoid trigonometric functions when solving this integral, here's an elementary way of tackling the integrand. First, call the integral $I$ and use integration by parts, with $u=\sqrt{x^2+a^2}$ and $v=x$.

$$I\equiv\int\sqrt{x^2+a^2}\,\mathrm dx=x\sqrt{x^2+a^2}-\int\frac {x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}\,\mathrm dx\tag{1}$$

Next, we can also rewrite our integral as

$$I=\int\frac {x^2+a^2}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}\,\mathrm dx=a^2\int\frac {\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}+\int\frac {x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}\,\mathrm dx\tag{2}$$

Observe that adding equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ together eliminate the $x^2/\sqrt{x^2+a^2}$ integral, leaving

$$I=\frac 12x\sqrt{x^2+a^2}+\frac 12a^2\int\frac {\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}$$

The last integral might seem difficult, but there is a crafty substitution one can use, namely $z=x+\sqrt{x^2+a^2}$ (can you see why?). This kind of substitution is called an Euler Substitution of the First Kind. Putting everything together, then

$$\int\sqrt{x^2+a^2}\,\mathrm dx\color{blue}{=\frac 12x\sqrt{x^2+a^2}+\frac 12a^2\log\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+a^2}\right)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your substitution would work if you had something like $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}$. But now we get $tdt=xdx$ which does not tell us much since we do not have any $x\cdot dx$ in the original equation. We would get something like this $$\int\sqrt{x^2+a^2}dx=\int tdx=\int t\cdot \frac{t}{x}dt = \int \frac{t^2}{\sqrt{t^2-a^2}}dt$$ which doesn't get rid of the square root and you will still need an trigonometric substitution.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is already been spotted in above two answers. So, I'm leaving that part.
Now, you can try substituting - $x=a \tan{t}$ ...
Here's the complete process,
$$x=a\tan{t}$$
$$d{x}=a{\sec^{2}t}{d{t}}$$
Your integral now becomes -
$$I=\int \sqrt{a^2+a^2 \tan^{2}t} (a \sec^{2}tdt)$$
$$I=\int a\sqrt{1+\tan^{2}t} (a \sec^{2}tdt)$$
$$I=a^{2}\int ( \sec^{3}tdt)$$
$$I=a^{2}\int ( \sec^{2}t )\sec{t} dt$$
Now, you can use integration by parts considering $u=\sec{t}$ and $v=\sec^{2}t$
$$I=a^{2}[{\sec{t} \tan{t} - \int (\sec{t} \tan^{2}t)dt}]$$
$$I=a^{2}[{\sec{t} \tan{t} - \int (\sec{t} (\sec^{2}t - 1))dt}]$$
$$I=a^{2} \sec{t} \tan{t} - a^{2}\int (\sec^{3}t)dt + a^{2}\int (\sec{t})dt$$
Now, $a^{2}\int (\sec^{3}t)dt$ is nothing but I...
So, our integral becomes -
$$I=\frac{a^{2} \sec{t} \tan{t} + a^{2} \log_e( \sec{t} + \tan{t})}{2}+C$$

Since... $a \tan{t} = x$
$$\tan{t}=\frac {x}{a}$$
and
$$\sec{t}=\sqrt{\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}} +1}$$
$$\sec{t}=\frac{\sqrt({x}^{2}+{a}^{2})}{a}$$

Substituting these values in above integrated equation gives -

$$I=\frac{a^{2} (\frac{\sqrt({x}^{2}+{a}^{2})}{a}) (\frac {x}{a}) + a^{2} \log_e( (\frac{\sqrt({x}^{2}+{a}^{2})}{a}) + (\frac {x}{a}))}{2}+C$$
$$I=\frac{x}{2} \sqrt({x}^{2}+{a}^{2}) + \frac{a^{2}}{2} \log_e(x+ \sqrt({x}^{2}+{a}^{2}))+C_1$$
Here, $C_1 = C- \frac{a^{2}}{2} \log_e{a}$